# What does the 2-1.1.1:1.0 string mean in the usb device path?

Tags: usb

I have the following path to consider:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1.1:1.0/
```

But when I look at `lsusb` output, I can see something like this:

```
# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

So which one of the devices is described by the string 2-1.1.1:1.0? And what's the purpose of the individual characters: `-`, `.` and `:`.

Comment: [`bus-port.port.port:config.interface`](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6)

Comment: That's a nice FAQ!

Comment: Just had the exact same question, so I turned @don_crissti's comment into an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linux USB FAQ #6](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6) (thanks @don_crissti, see comments on question):

> In other words, the name starts with the bus number followed by a '-'. Then comes the sequence of port numbers for each of the intermediate hubs along the path to the device.
>
> For example, "1-1" is a device plugged into bus 1, port 1. It happens to be a hub, and "1-1.3" is the device plugged into port 3 of that hub. That device is another hub, and "1-1.3.1" is the device plugged into its port 1.

If your device has multiple endpoints, they will appear after a colon eg. `1-1.3.1:1.4` is the 4th endpoint/interface using configuration 1.